# Python program to extend short urls that integrates with Stata

Tags: python-2.7, stata

I have a dataset containing thousands of tweets. Some of those contain urls but most of them are in the classical shortened forms used in Twitter. I need something that gets the full urls so that I can check the presence of some particular websites. I have solved the problem in Python like this:

```
import urllib2
url_filename='C:\Users\Monica\Documents\Pythonfiles\urlstrial.txt'
url_filename2='C:\Users\Monica\Documents\Pythonfiles\output_file.txt'
url_file= open(url_filename, 'r')
out = open(url_filename2, 'w')
for line in url_file:
   tco_url = line.strip('\n')
   req = urllib2.urlopen(tco_url)
   print >>out, req.url
url_file.close()
out.close()
```

Which works but requires that I export my urls from Stata to a .txt file and then reimport the full urls. Is there some version of my Python script that would allow me to integrate the task in Stata using the shell command? I have quite a lot of different .dta files and I would ideally like to avoid appending them all just to execute this task.

Thanks in advance for any answer!

Comment: What does the Python script do precisely? I think I can guess except for  `req = urllib2.urlopen(tco_url)`

Comment: It transforms the tiny-urls used in twitter, like for example bit.ly/162VWRZ  in full-blown urls with the complete website, so that I can then, say match the linking patterns of users to their political affiliation.

Comment: That's not to my knowledge a built-in Stata command or function.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, this is possible without leaving Stata.  I am using a Mac running OS X.  The details might differ on your operating system, which I am guessing is Windows.

**Python and Stata Method**

Say we have the following trivial Python program, called `hello.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import csv

data = [['name', 'message'], ['Monica', 'Hello World!']]
with open('data.csv', 'w') as wsock:
    wtr = csv.writer(wsock)
    for i in data:
        wtr.writerow(i)
    wsock.close()
```

This "program" just writes some fake data to a file called data.csv in the script's working directory.  Now make sure the script is executable: `chmod 755 hello.py`.

From within Stata, you can do the following:

```
! ./hello.py
* The above line called the Python program, which created a data.csv file.
insheet using data.csv, comma clear names case
list

     +-----------------------+
     |   name        message |
     |-----------------------|
  1. | Monica   Hello World! |
     +-----------------------+
```

This is a simple example.  The full process for your case will be:

1. Write file to disk with the URLs, using `outsheet` or some other command
2. Use `!` to call the Python script
3. Read the output into Stata using `insheet` or `infile` or some other command
4. Cleanup by deleting files with `capture erase my_file_on_disk.csv`

Let me know if that is not clear.  It works fine on *nix; as I said, Windows might be a little different.  If I had a Windows box I would test it.

**Pure Stata Solution (kind of a hack)**

Also, I think what you want to accomplish can be done completely in Stata, but it's a hack.  Here are two programs.  The first simply opens a log file and makes a request for the url (which is the first argument).  The second reads that log file and uses regular expressions to find the url that Stata was redirected to.

```
capture program drop geturl
program define geturl
    * pass short url as first argument (e.g. http://bit.ly/162VWRZ)
    capture erase temp_log.txt
    log using temp_log.txt
    copy `1' temp_web_file
end
```

The above program will not finish because the `copy` command will fail (intentionally).  It also doesn't clean up after itself (intentionally).  So I created the next program to read what happened (and get the URL redirect).

```
capture program drop longurl
program define longurl, rclass
    * find the url in the log file created by geturl
    capture log close
    loc long_url = ""
    file open urlfile using temp_log.txt , read
    file read urlfile line
    while r(eof) == 0 {
        if regexm("`line'", "server says file permanently redirected to (.+)") == 1 {
            loc long_url = regexs(1)
        }
        file read urlfile line
    }
    file close urlfile
    return local url "`long_url'"
end
```

You can use it like this:

```
geturl  http://bit.ly/162VWRZ
longurl
di "The long url is:  `r(url)'"
* The long url is:  http://www.ciwati.it/2013/06/10/wdays/?utm_source=twitterfeed&
* > utm_medium=twitter
```

You should run them one after the other.  Things might get ugly using this solution, but it does find the URL you are looking for.  May I suggest that another approach is to contact the shortening service and ask nicely for some data?

If someone at Stata is reading this, it would be nice to have `copy` return HTTP response header information.  Doing this entirely in Stata is a little out there.  Personally I would use entirely Python for this sort of thing and use Stata for the analysis of data once I had everything I needed.

Comment: First of all, thanks for the answer. I imagined that the only solution had to be something like the one you proposed. I was wondering if there was a more direct way that did not include an outsheet call, with an insheet since to get the data ready for those commands and then back into my file I have to use a collapse and then a merge. I'm interested in your solution purely in Stata. I didn't know about the command copy but even reading the help I can't seem to figure out how to use it to solve my problem. I'm not checking for existence. I want the long version of the shortened urls in twitter.

Comment: @Bye11 I have revised the answer with a 100% Stata solution.  It still requires file IO.  There is no way around that.  Also, my proposed solution is far from elegant.

Comment: Thank you so much for your solutions. I'll try them both and see which one works faster. Also, you're right, I probably should do everything in Python, but I need the file in Stata first because I have a do that cleans it thoroughly before getting to the urls that I need lengthened and being just a beginner in Python I don't know enough to make the same cleanup process happen there. Thanks a lot for all your work on my answer!